# Python - re.sub without replacing a part of regex

Tags: python, regex

So for example I have a string "perfect bear hunts" and I want to replace the word before occurence of "bear" with word "the".

So the resulting string would be "the bear hunts"

I thought I would use

```
re.sub("\w+ bear","the","perfect bear hunts")
```

but it replaces "bear" too. How do I exclude bear from being replaced while also having it used in matching?

Comment: @Rawing very good, edited it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like the other answers, I’d use a positive lookahead assertion.

Then to fix the issue raised by Rawing in a couple of the comments (what about words like “beard”?), I’d add `(\b|$)`. This matches a word boundary or the end of the string, so you only match on the word `bear`, and nothing longer.

So you get the following:

```
import re

def bear_replace(string):
    return re.sub(r"\w+ (?=bear(\b|$))", "the ", string)
```

and test cases (using pytest):

```
import pytest

@pytest.mark.parametrize('string, expected', [
    ("perfect bear swims", "the bear swims"),

    # We only capture the first word before 'bear
    ("before perfect bear swims", "before the bear swims"),

    # 'beard' isn't captured
    ("a perfect beard", "a perfect beard"),

    # We handle the case where 'bear' is the end of the string
    ("perfect bear", "the bear"),

    # 'bear' is followed by a non-space punctuation character
    ("perfect bear-string", "the bear-string"),
])
def test_bear_replace(string, expected):
    assert bear_replace(string) == expected
```

Comment: Sorry for being nitpicky, but I want to point out that `bear(\s|$)` won't match if the word "bear" is followed by any kind of punctuation - "the bear." or "the bear, who" for example. I'd suggest using a word boundary `\b` instead (though admittedly that isn't a perfect solution either; it would match "bear-sized" for example).

Answer (score 2):

Use a Positive Lookahead to replace everything before bear:

```
re.sub(".+(?=bear )","the ","perfect bear swims")
```

`.+` will capture any character (except for line terminators).

Comment: This will replace literally everything before the characters "bear", not just the word before it. Try this on "my long beard" to see the problem...

Comment: Updated with a space. Thanks for the hint ;)

Comment: It still turns "a big bear " into "thebear " instead of "a the bear ". The OP said they want to replace _the word_ before "bear", not _the entire string_. You went and changed OP's `\w+` for absolutely no reason whatsoever.

Answer (score 1):

[`Look Behind` and `Look Ahead`](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) regular expressions is what you are looking for.

```
re.sub(".+(?=bear)", "the ", "prefect bear swims")
```

Comment: This will replace literally everything before the characters "bear". Try this on "my long beard".

Comment: This will yield 'thebear swims'

Answer (score 1):

An alternative to using lookaheads:

Capture the part you want to keep using a group `()` and reinsert it using `\1` in the replacement.

```
re.sub("\w+ (bear)",r"the \1","perfect bear swims")
```

Comment: Note that this will also match words like "beard". You should consider adding a word boundary `\b`.